# Changing Styles of Elements by Pan Gesture in React Native

Tags: react-native, gesture, react-animations

I have a divided screen by squares and need to change their colors by touching with a finger continuously with pan gesture.

[image]

At first, I thought I could do that by getting position of my finger by pan handler and find which element is located in that location, so that I could change it's color. But it didn't work as I thought.
I am stucked at this problem and wondering about your opinions.

Comment: Hi Murat, you could try to explain what you tried and how that didn't work. You could also share a minimal part of your code tu make us understand what you are doing and maybe point you towards what is going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide a [PanResponder](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder) for the parent View of those squares.

```
// define the constants
const rows = 10;
const columns = 5;
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

Inside **onPanResponderMove** write this logic.

```
 onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
    let i = 0;
    let x = evt.nativeEvent.pageX;
    let y = evt.nativeEvent.pageY;
    let percentageX = Math.floor(x / (width / columns));
    let percentageY = Math.floor(y / (height / rows));
    i = percentageX + columns * percentageY;
    this.onChangeItem(i);  // <-- i will provide you the index of current touch 
  },
```

Inside onChangeItem function check when the index is changing while moving finger.

```
onChangeItem = (index) => {
  if (this.index !== index) {
    // do operations here with index.
  }
};

....
```

Here is my **Example code**: [PanhandlerAnimations](https://snack.expo.io/@aswinc/9630db)

## **Result:**

[image]

Comment: I think you have just saved my day. Thank you so much!